# Can anyone in here explain to me what exactly is 'Quasi-Generalised Co-ordinates'?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, definition

This comes straight up from a certain text that I was going through, which of course is in the form of a question which asks 'A solid cylinder is rolling without slipping and how many generalized co-ordinates are required. Are there any quasi-generalised co-ordinates?'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which text? Which page?

Comment: Is there an explanation (somewhere) in the text itself? Is there an index that references those terms?

Comment: I apologize for commenting really late on this, but I'm really unsure about its origin. When I said a certain text, I meant the assignment that my professor gave me the other day.